# filter drop-shadow for Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, dropshadow

I am using `drop-shadow` filter on a curved png which works nicely in any other browser than IE.

Check out the boxes here: https://www.yogidia.com/builder
(Three boxes just below 'Yoga Sequence Builder 3 in 1:')

Here is my code:

```
.curved::after {
    content: "";
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12));
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12));
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -39px;
    left: 0;
}
```

I need help on reproducing same effect in IE.

I have tried

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow
```

and

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow
```

but without success :/

Comment: Which version of IE needs the support?

Comment: IE 10 + 11 should do fine...

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css-filters/embed Well, since filters in general aren't supported, I suggest you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx this article, but don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `box-shadow`? Using a circle as example:

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3f0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"><div>
```

And in your example, using a bottom image isn't really the best way to go, what if there is a change in width? It's not very responsive, I'd advise you to use this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#box::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: -30px;
  border-radius: 00px 0px 50% 50%;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: box-shadow with border-radius works but does not produce the [exact] curvature that I want. So a solution to the original question is preferred.

Comment: it doesn't work for an image with a transparent background

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVG filter for IE. I have tested with IE10.

```css
div
{
 width:32px;
 line-height:32px;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#4af;
 filter: url(#drop-shadow); /* set SVG filter */
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="drop-shadow">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.5"/>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/>
        <feFlood flood-color="#0f0"/>
        <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
</svg>

<div>A</div>
```